# Sending money through remittance to previous employer against in lieu of full and final settlement

Tags: taxes, india, international-transfer, payment

I resigned from my previous job. As part of the final settlement, there is some money that I need to pay my employer [Unsettled expenses, etc]. I need to pay that off through remittance. Does this involves any tax implication or any procedure which I need to take care of?

Comment: You owe money to your former employer? Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: yes, correct. i resigned to that employer and now as full and final settlement, they say that there is an amount i owe to them and i must pay them for full and final settlement. so now, i am thinking to remit same amount to the employer.

Answer (score 1):

Nope pay the employer back the due does not involve any tax. Just keep a record of the transaction so that its available as reference.

Comment: How did you know OP is from India?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer OP himself had tagged it as India. I just added few tags and made edits on question.